# differential equation - writting an integral to determine the periode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my differential equation is

$$x''(t)=x(t)^2-x(t)$$

the energy function is

$$E(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{y^2}{2}$$

I only consider solutions with initial velocity $x'(0)=0$, and I have found that there are periodic solutions for $0<x<1$, and I'm asked to determine the period of those solutions in terms of an integral depending on $x(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E(x,y)=\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{y^2}2=C\\
\frac{dx}{dt}=y=\sqrt{2C-x^2+2x^3/3}\\
Period = \int dt = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2C-x^2+2x^3/3}}$$